# I updated my Unity, now prefab overrides are no longer bold. Is there a way to have this back?

Tags: unity

I updated from Unity 2021 to 2023.2.14f and it seems that Unity now marks a property overridden only with a **thin blue line** at the edge of the inspector.

However in the **previous version they were also bold**, so it was quite visible which property is overridden and which is not.

I think knowing this information is crucial, so making it visible is very important. But maybe I just develop in some bad way.

Is there a way to **customize Unity so overrides are bold again**?

Comment: I use the latest version of Unity (2023.3.20f1) and my overrides are bold.

Comment: @Pow Updated to post to feature the actual version of my Unity. However are you sure you typed that right? I think the latest 2023 version is mine: 2023.2.14. I don't remember 2023.3 being released

Comment: @Pow Oh, or do you mean Unity 6? So I guess this is a temporary thing and they reverted this change in the next feature release?

Comment: @Tudvari 2023.3.0a18 is the latest alpha build version that my hub is offering me

Comment: @Zibelas Strange, for me it's the 6000.0.0b11 Beta. But maybe because my Hub is on the beta channel instead of production. Its version is 3.7.0.

Comment: @Tudvari Sorry, I meant 2022.3.20f1